# PHPExcel: Downloading spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

For a long time now, I have been trying to give users the ability to 'save as' or 'open' the created spreadsheet using the dialog box.

This is what I tried, I am getting no errors, just gibberish characters on the screen:

```
//CREATE SPEADSHEET

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

// We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

// It will be called file.xls
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');

// Write file to the browser
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with figuring this one out.

Comment: do you have anything echo'd before you set the header? have you looked at the headers you get on the screen with gibberish to make sure they are correct?

Comment: Do the "save as" and open the file in a text editor: then look for white space (spaces, tabs, new lines, etc) as the first or last characters in the file, a BOM marker, or any visible PHP error messages in the file

Comment: @Mark Baker, I can't "save as" and I am not getting any errors, that is the problem.

Comment: In that case, "view source" and look for the aforementioned. The most likely cause is that you're echoing some output other than the Excel file

Comment: Thanks for the reply. No, no data is echoed before the headers.... What do you mean by "have you looked at the headers you get on the screen with gibberish to make sure they are correct?" Sorry, I am new to all this.

Comment: Look at the html headers return by the server in your browser.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That is not the problem. I checked, nothing seems to be wrong. Its still not working.

Comment: If the output is appearing on screen rather than triggering the browser's download dialogue, then the headers aren't doing their job. Ensure that you have full error logging to display, and see if that gives any clues

Comment: if you're trying this in IE over SSL, it's is an exception.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried your part of the code and it worked just fine, if you are getting just gibberish, the problem coud actually be on the part where you are generating the table, check that part to see if there is any mistake, bellow is the code I used to test it:

```
 define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');

    /** Include PHPExcel */
    require_once '../../PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';

    // Create new PHPExcel object
    $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

    // Set document properties
    $objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Lumina")
                         ->setLastModifiedBy("Lumina")
                         ->setTitle("Entry members")
                         ->setSubject("Entry members")
                         ->setDescription("List of members participting.")
                         ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
                         ->setCategory("Entry members");

        // Add some data                 
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', $row_titles['TITLE01'])
        ->setCellValue('B1', $row_titles['TITLE02'])
        ->setCellValue('C1', $row_titles['TITLE03'])
        ->setCellValue('D1', $row_titles['TITLE04'])
        ->setCellValue('E1', $row_titles['TITLE05'])
        ->setCellValue('F1', $row_titles['TITLE06'])
        ->setCellValue('G1', $row_titles['TITLE07'])
        ->setCellValue('H1', $row_titles['TITLE08'])
        ->setCellValue('I1', $row_titles['TITLE09'])
        ->setCellValue('J1', $row_titles['TITLE10'])
        ->setCellValue('K1', $row_titles['TITLE11'])
        ->setCellValue('L1', $row_titles['TITLE12'])
        ->setCellValue('M1', $row_titles['TITLE13'])
        ->setCellValue('N1', $row_titles['TITLE14'])
        ->setCellValue('O1', $row_titles['TITLE15'])
        ->setCellValue('P1', $row_titles['TITLE16'])
        ->setCellValue('Q1', $row_titles['TITLE17'])
        ->setCellValue('R1', $row_titles['TITLE18'])
        ->setCellValue('S1', $row_titles['TITLE19'])
        ->setCellValue('T1', $row_titles['TITLE20'])
        ->setCellValue('U1', $row_titles['TEAM_TX'])
        ->setCellValue('V1', $row_titles['T_SHIRT_SIZE'])
        ->setCellValue('W1', $row_titles['INPUT1_TX'])
        ->setCellValue('X1', $row_titles['INPUT2_TX'])
        ->setCellValue('Y1', $row_titles['INPUT3_TX'])
        ->setCellValue('Z1', $row_titles['INPUT4_TX']);

        // Rename worksheet
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Participants');

        // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

        // Save Excel5 file
        //echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel5 format" , EOL;
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
        $objWriter->save(str_replace('.html', '.xls', __FILE__));

        // We'll be outputting an excel file
        header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

        // It will be called file.xls
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');

        // Write file to the browser
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

I hope this can be of any help as I am also new to PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i was getting gibberish in the response. and the excel could not be open.
The solution is not to use form submit or ajax call, only use document.location to forward the process of the excel generator.
For example:

```
document.location="/php/Controller/YnrAPICall.php?is_string=1&params="+ JSON.stringify(params);
```